# custom search control for task list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a sequential Sharepoint Foundation (Share point 2010) workflow in Visual Studio.
I can create costume tasks using a CreateTaskWithContentType  activity, I need to create custom search control  for this task list that meet my business can you please guide me

Thanks